# Why is my question put on hold?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, specific-question, closed-questions

I posted this question:

[Google Map based on ASP.NET/SQL database field "Google Map Link"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20610502/google-map-based-on-asp-net-sql-database-field-google-map-link)

I don't know the reason why this question is put on hold?

Comment: You can find the reason below your question.

Answer (score 8):

It has been placed on hold because, as the on hold reason states:

> Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

You haven't provided details of any work attempted, where you're at in the project, or really anything beyond "I have a string in a database, how do I turn that into a map?"