# Please specify why my question is on hold

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

I don't find any post talk about running of TCP port on long polling. Why my post is on hold?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20736575/how-to-scale-up-a-web-server-supporting-long-polling

Comment: "There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs."  Given your final question is "how do I support 20k users," you're basically asking for a book.

Comment: It's also not good to cross-post across Stack Exchange sites. Each site specializes in a certain topic, and managing a web server would likely be more on topic on Server Fault anyway.

Comment: Reading the close reason often helps :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is my question put on hold?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212303/why-is-my-question-put-on-hold)

Comment: Definitely not a duplicate, @Sandesh.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Why it was put on hold

I won't talk about other reasonings whether you posted the same question somewhere else or not. But I will just talk about the current reason for the holding of question.

Moderator [Andrew Barber](https://stackoverflow.com/users/237838/andrew-barber) put the question on hold, not because it was duplicate, neither because of being off-topic nor any other reason. Reason was told at the bottom! Too Broad means they might be on-topic and their problem is not solved here on Stack Overflow, but they are lengthy and need a whole lot of space to be solved!

#### Holding reasons and information

A qoute from the information block of the holding reason:

> There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format.

Which means, that this question is too broad, which would require a lengthy answer, and cannot be solved in just 3 - 5 paragraphic answers!

Answerer would either have to provide you with a link to some Online E-Book to go and study further for the problem or he would have to write alot, just to specify the problem!

#### Suggestion from the moderator

Remaining part of the holding reason is as follows:

> Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Which means, that you might want to edit the question, and split it down into some pieces so that answers can be some paragraphs.

#### Avoid discussions on Stack Overflow; they are off-topic

Please note that Stack Overflow is a Q&A site, not a general discussion forum. So, a to-the-point question is on-topic and to-the-point answer is up-voted here! Anything not related to the terms of the site is either removed by the moderators or is flagged and action is taken relatedly.

#### My Suggestion:

So, I would like to advice you to please shorten down the question, to make it specific to a problem and then ask it! Answerers would provide you with a 2 - 4 paragraphic answer and you'll get the problem solved!

Once you have editted the question, please vote for reopening of the question. Don't worry, the question is not flagged duplicate so it will come back in action, once you edit it!

Good luck! :)

Answer (score 4):

**Major Premise:** Only questions that are about programming belong on Stack Overflow.

**Minor Premise:** Your question doesn't have anything to do with programming.

**Conclusion:** Your question does not belong on Stack Overflow.

Why "Too broad" was the actual chosen reason for closure, I couldn't say. It's possible for more than one reason to apply, though, each justifying closure.

Answer (score 2):

> Why my question is on hold ?

Because:

1. You posted same question in multiple Stack Exchange site.
2. Stack Overflow is for programming related problems. And each site has its own purpose.

And finally, if you don't get an answer on Server Fault, start bounty to attract users.